# Describing a Concept as "Delusional" or "Illusional" Here?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

So I wonder if there is any chance for such a use of the term "delusional" to make sense (even for exaggeration): We will show that such-and-so concept can be delusional. If not, would "illusional" be a better fit here?

What I would like to convey is that this such-and-so concept is usually unquestioned, but, my research shows that this concept may not be entirely reliable in certain situations.

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer to your actual question. I think more context would help (like maybe a statement of the concept you have in mind). But I wonder if the word you are thinking of is "illusory". People will certainly know what you mean by "illusional", but "illusory" is more commonly found in dictionaries, and I'm pretty sure it means the same thing.

Comment: @LorelC., Thanks for feedback. It is just that the concept is mathematical (almost no counterpart in life) . To prevent controversies or distractions, I decided to make it implicit. I would just like to know if there is possibility for it to be meaningful to write something like "the concept is delusional".

Comment: @LorelC., Or maybe delusive also suitable?

Comment: Just a note on "delusional": to me it gives a strong (and insulting) suggestion that the one who believes the false concept is insane and even ridiculous. Not sure if you want that kind of "baggage"? ... As for "delusive"? Maybe(?). I don't know the subtle connotations of that word. (I was surprised even to find it in the dictionary.)

Comment: The two words have clearly different definitions. I can't think of a situation where one could be considered as similar to the other.

Comment: It is usually better to be explicit rather than hide details behind "such and so".  Providing more context rarely makes the question less clear.]

Answer (score 1):

An 'illusion' is a false *perception*, whereas a 'delusion' is a false *belief*. A person may see an illusion and not believe it because they recognise it as such, so one does not necessarily lead to the other.

Despite this close similarity in definitions, we don't really use "illusional" the same way as "delusional". We may say a person or an idea is 'delusional', I've never heard a person called 'illusional' before.

You said that you are trying to refer to a widely-held belief that is questionable but has largely gone unchallenged. I think that words like '*myth*' or '*fallacy*' might be better in these circumstances. Although these words are synonymous with "delusion", they refer exclusively to the idea itself rather than the person. "Delusional", when said about a person, often implies some kind of mental deficiency.

Comment: Actually, now you put it like that, I think a *person* suffering from a delusion is called "delusional" and an *idea* that is a delusion is called *delusory*.  At any rate, whether or not "delusional" can describe an idea, "delusory" is unambiguous, it can only describe an idea, not a person.  Which might be an advantage in this case, if you want to avoid implying that your colleagues are mentally unbalanced.  Not using "delusion" at all is still preferable, though, for that reason!

Comment: @A.B. That's not correct - "delusional" can refer to a person, or ideas that are inspired by delusion. "Delusory" means *to have the effect of deluding others*. For example, you and your comment are delusional, but there is also a great risk that others might believe your comment, and so it is also delusory.

Comment: Merriam-Webster's definition (though arguably not the example it gives) and Thefreedictionary agree with you, Lexico.com https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/delusory and every time I remember actually hearing this word *used* agree with me.  The point is, at least, arguable (although fair enough to point out there's disagreement).  Also there's no need to be insulting.

Answer (score 0):

To say it is "delusional" suggest it is an insane fantasy.  It is much stronger than "not always reliable".

> It is delusional to think that we can double the amount of Carbon Dioxide in the atmosphere without having some effect on the climate.

Illusion suggests that people have been tricked.

> Climate scientists attempt to create the illusion of a world on the brink of disaster.

Your suggestion in the second paragraph can be used:

> We will show that such-and-so concept may not be entirely reliable in certain situations.